# Creating users in CAS server

Tags: settings, ubuntu-20.04, cas

I created a new CAS server in ubuntu 20.04, and logged in with the default username and password.

I followed [this link](https://medium.com/swlh/install-cas-server-with-db-authentication-8ff52234f52) to create the setup.

Now I need to create users and admin users in the setup for the testing.

How can I do that?

I followed [this document](https://dacurry-tns.github.io/deploying-apereo-cas/building_server_dashboard_configure-admin-pages-properties.html#create-the-admusersproperties-file) to make default user to admin user but it is not working.

Can you please help to create new users.

Thanks and advance.

Answer (score 1):

You already create your admin users following the first link:

```
mgmt.userPropertiesFile=file:/etc/cas/config/users.json
```

and:

```json
{
  "user1@test.com" : {
    "@class" : "org.apereo.cas.mgmt.authz.json.UserAuthorizationDefinition",
    "roles" : [ "ROLE_ADMIN" ]
  }
}
```

You need to have these admin accounts in your database to be able to authenticate them via the CAS server.

Comment: I created a new postgres db and added all the configuration given in first link, but, it is failing to connect the db.`2023-03-13 11:31:48,232 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationManager] - <Authentication has failed. Credentials may be incorrect or CAS cannot find authentication handler that supports [UsernamePasswordCredential(username=<usermane.email.com>, source=null, customFields={})] of type [UsernamePasswordCredential]. Examine the configuration to ensure a method of authentication is defined and analyze CAS logs at DEBUG level to trace the authentication event.>`

Comment: You should turn on DEBUG logs on the org.apereo.cas.adaptors.jdbc package.